# Encryption and decryption in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I have been looking for ideas on encrypting and decrypting values in Laravel (like VIN Numbers, Employee ID Card Numbers, Social Security Numbers, etc.) and recently found this on the Laravel website: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/encryption

My question is, how would I print the decrypted values on a blade template? I could see going through the controller and setting a variable and then printing it to a Blade, but I was curious as to how I would also print a decrypted value to an index? Like so...

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
{{$employee->decrypted value somehow}}
{{$employee->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Just do `{{ decrypt($employee->ssn) }}` in the view. Simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can handle encrypted attributes with a trait (`app/EncryptsAttributes.php`):

```php
namespace App;

trait EncryptsAttributes {

    public function attributesToArray() {
        $attributes = parent::attributesToArray();
        foreach($this->getEncrypts() as $key) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $attributes)) {
                $attributes[$key] = decrypt($attributes[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $attributes;
    }

    public function getAttributeValue($key) {
        if(in_array($key, $this->getEncrypts())) {
            return decrypt($this->attributes[$key]);
        }
        return parent::getAttributeValue($key);
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $this->getEncrypts())) {
            $this->attributes[$key] = encrypt($value);
        } else {
            parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected function getEncrypts() {
        return property_exists($this, 'encrypts') ? $this->encrypts : [];
    }

}
```

Use it in your models when necessary:

```php
class Employee extends Model {

    use EncryptsAttributes;

    protected $encrypts = ['cardNumber', 'ssn'];

}
```

Then you can get and set the attributes without thinking about the encryption:

```
$employee->ssn = '123';
{{ $employee->ssn }}
```

Comment: hi i implement the same and its working with getattribute and setattribute but didnt get why use attributesToArray

Comment: `attributesToArray()` is necessary for `$model->toArray()` and `$model->toJson()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom function or [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your model.

Say your model is `Employee` and your encrypted column is `ssn`. You could do that:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    // With a function
    public function decryptSsn()
    {
        return decrypt($this->attributes['ssn']);
    }

    // With an accessor
    public function getDecryptedSsnAttribute()
    {
        return decrypt($this->attributes['ssn']);
    }
}
```

In case you go with function, you'd call it like this:

```
$employee->decryptSsn();
```

And if you go with an accessor, you would call it like this:

```
$employee->decrypted_ssn;
```

Comment: This seems to be overcomplicating things a little when a simple `{{ decrypt($employee->ssn) }}` in the view would do.

Comment: That would work too, yes. I'd suggest going with a function/accessor for easier maintenance

Comment: I would disagree that having a separate function or accessor for each and every encrypted attribute is easily maintainable. I'd be more inclined to inherit a function (class or trait) which takes the attribute name, and handles the decryption instead.

Comment: `So if you plan to print it multiple times within the same request cycle, the accessor is better.` - how is it better? The decrypted value isn't cached. So what's the difference?

Comment: @fubar You're right about the decrypted value not being cached. I thought it gets appended to `$attributes` array the first time it's called and gets called from there from thereon. Tested and I was wrong. As for function being more maintainable, yes having a trait or appending another type to `$casts` would be even more maintainable. But having `decrypt($m->ssn)` in many views will likely happen and this is step 1 to easier maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

use `appends` in models. easier to use anywhere without repeating using encrypt/decrypt helper

```
class Employee extends Model {
     protected $appends = [
           'encrypted_ssn_number',
     ];

     protected $hidden = ['ssn']; //if you want to hide from json of actual value of ssn

     public function getEncryptedSsnNumberAttribute()
     {
         return encrypt($this->ssn); // md5($this->ssn);  //bcrypt($this->ssn)
         // if $this->ssn not working, use $this->attribute['ssn']
     }
}
```

use in model

```
{{ employee->encrypted_ssn_number }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle with simple create a custom trait in app/trait Encryptable.php

```
namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

trait Encryptable
{
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
    if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
        try {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $value = null;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    $value = $this->attributes[$key];
    if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
        $this->attributes[$key] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }
    return $this;
}
}
```

Use it in your models only those columns which you want to encryption.

```
use App\Traits\Encryptable;
class ABC extends Model {

use Encryptable;

protected $encryptable= ['name', 'description'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create file `Encryptable.php` inside `app/Traits`

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;
use Crypt;

trait Encryptable
{

     public function toArray()
     {
        $array = parent::toArray();
        foreach ($array as $key => $attribute) {
            if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && $array[$key]!='') {
                try {
                $array[$key] = Crypt::decrypt($array[$key]);
               } catch (\Exception $e) {
               }
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        try {
            $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
            if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && $value!='') {
                $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
                return $value;
            }
            return $value;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }
        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

inside your model :

```
use App\Traits\Encryptable;

class Employee extends Model {

    use Encryptable;
    protected $encryptable = ['cardNumber', 'ssn'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use save id in URL Laravel encrypt and decrypt this method

```
{{encrypt($edit_template->id)}}  

{{decrypt($id)}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create one helper file and inside that file create function that will be accessible from any views.
Follow this link for create helper: https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-create-custom-helper-in-laravel-55

```
function decryptText($text) {
   return decrypt($text);
}
```

and use inside view like this :

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
 {{decryptText($employee->encryptedText)}}
 {{$employee->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Totally unneeded function.

Comment: That will only use full when you are using same logic at multiple times and you want to modify decrypt and encrypt logic globally. Other wise you have to modify to multiple location. It is handy just change on one place will select to all over the application.

Comment: What is the gain of using `decryptText($text)` instead of `decrypt($text)`?

Comment: function decryptText($text) {
   return decrypt($text);//  if you have multiple logic here like
   //decrypt(anotherfunction(anotherfunction($text))) like so...
}

Comment: It's called [code bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat) what you did there.

Comment: "Yo dawg, I heard you like helpers, so I put a helper in your helper so you can helper while you helper..."