# How to add encrypt task before inputdata goes to dastabase?

Tags: laravel-5

I made contact-form which all input data goes to a MySQL database.
And when it's saved, it auto replies an email to the customer and me.
This works fine. The next step would be to encrypt that.

Where do I have to put the encrypt task and how?

I just did

`php artisan key:generate`

and

```
    {{ $contact->name = \Crypt::encrypt($contact->name) }}
```

I can see encrypt data.

here is my code input date goes database

`Contact::create($request->all());`

and I would like to know how to decrypt and show all data.

Contact.php ( I fixed twice now)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Contact extends Model
{

       use EncryptsAttributes;

         protected $fillable = [
    'type',
    'name',
    'email',
    'gender',       
    'body'

];

use EncryptsAttributes;

protected $encrypts = [
   'type',
    'name',
    'email',
    'gender',       
    'body'
];

    static $types = [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4'
    ];



}
```

and this is my confirm.blade.php
For checking I would like to see the encryped data

```
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <td>{{ $contact->name }} 
                         (This isn't encrypt)

                         <br>
          {{ $contact->name = \Crypt::encrypt($contact->name) }}
          (I this this before I asked here. I can see name encrypeted)


                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

This is my name section of  index.blade.php  file

```
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('name', 'YOUR NAME:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

now I got this error 
 Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
Add [_token] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Contact].

```
foreach ($this->fillableFromArray($attributes) as $key => $value) {
        $key = $this->removeTableFromKey($key);


    // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable" array
    // which means only those attributes may be set through mass assignment to
    // the model, and all others will just get ignored for security reasons.
    if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
        $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
    } elseif ($totallyGuarded) {
        throw new MassAssignmentException(sprintf(
            'Add [%s] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
            $key, get_class($this)
        ));
    }
}

return $this;
```

}

now i got this error

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\php\041951257234\resources\views\contacts\confirm.blade.php)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encryption and decryption in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503230/encryption-and-decryption-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Hi Jonas. Thank you for comment. sorry I'm still don't get it. I can encrypt one of each data and see it. but I don't know how to write all data as once before Contact::create($request->all());

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Did you use the code from the linked answer to adjust your `Contact` model?

Comment: What did you mean by "encrypt that". I assume you trying to encrypt the data when you save into database. For that, you can use the trait that @JonasStaudenmeir mentioned in his comment. It will encrypt the data when you store and decrypt the data when you get from database

Comment: also FYI: once you encrypt the data in the database you can't query it using where clause. So you have to get all and filter using collection methods. So consider using a database level encryption(https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html)

Comment: Thank you again Mr. @JonasStaudenmeir . sorry my English is not good. Mr. Ravisha Hesh said  your link can do what I want to do. so I tried again but it still doesn't work. I add my code and some comment Could you tell me what is problem?

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Ravisha Hesh . Sorry my English. now my mind is clear that Mr. Jonas send me a link can do what I want to do.  I post another code and my comment. And Thank you FYI that is very important and helped me. I remember that. for now as a studying laravel I will chose Encrypt way.

Comment: you have to add `use EncryptsAttributes;` after `class Contact extends Model
{
` also define `protected $encrypts = [];` array with field that you need to encrypt. Before all of that make sure to change the data type of every column that you are gonna encrypt to text. otherwise, it will save only part of the encrypted data and throw Invalid payload exception when decrypting.

Comment: Thank you again Mr. @Ravisha Hesh .  I fixed all except this line --> Before all of that make sure to change the data type of every column that you are gonna encrypt to text. "  I add my blade file. Could you tell me how?

Comment: you have to change the table column type from migrations to text

Comment: Thank you again Mr. @Ravisha Hesh . I change table colum type as TEXT. I got another code. i add above.  Contact.php   it was  protected $fillable  but now  protected $encrypts  that is the reason?

Comment: you have to add both, fillable array use to identify fields that are updatable by Model::create and Model::update methods. It's a Eloquent array. encrypts array use to identify fields that you want to encrypt

Comment: Mr. @Ravisha Hesh. Thank you . I understand . and I did what you said. now I got this error see above.  I update my Contact.php   is my code okay?

Comment: Why are trying to encrypt the name again in confirm.blade.php?

Comment: Mr. @Ravisha Hesh. sorry for made you confuse. It's just for studying for there is no mean I just wanted to encrypt all data name, email, body etc..

Comment: so just add name to encrypts array, and remove `{{ $contact->name = \Crypt::encrypt($contact->name) }}`

Comment: Mr. @Ravisha Hesh. Thank you so much! Finally it worked! I appreciate your skill and kindness!