# After add encryption function "The payload is invalid" error shows up

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use this gentleman's todo app and it works perfectly.

https://github.com/ericlie/Laravel-Simple-Todo-List#setting-up

I tried to add Encryption and Decryption into this app using this gentleman's answer.

[Encryption and decryption in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503230/encryption-and-decryption-in-laravel-5)

But I am getting this error after adding the code-

> The payload is invalid

I've been searching and trying the encryption and decryption functions but it always shows the same error.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

I would like to use encryption and decryption on Task table's **task** column and "users" tables **name** and **email** columns.

Here is my controller of task-

```
class Task extends Model
{
    // I add this 
    use EncryptsAttributes;
    protected $encrypts = ['task'];

   // original code
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Pankaj Thank you very much for edited my post.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Dear @Pankaj Thank you for answering me. No I didn't still having problem. Do you have idea to solve this?

Comment: Generally, this error pops up when you try to encrypt an already encrypted string. Can you update your question with the full updated code of EncryptAttirbutes trait, User model and the controller where you are trying to save the data? I will take a look and figure this out for you.

Comment: Dear @Pankaj Thank you very much for your big support. I post 3 code here model controller and Encrypt Attributes. I can't thank you enough ^^  https://jsfiddle.net/goldlight/su3mh2nt/4/

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at your code and get back to you shortly.

Comment: I have added an answer to your problem. Please take a look at it and let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the code that you shared and figured out the possible reason for your issue-

You are getting this error here on `return decrypt($this->attributes[$key])` in your **EncryptsAttributes.php** trait.

```
public function getAttributeValue($key) {
    if(in_array($key, $this->getEncrypts())) {
        return decrypt($this->attributes[$key]);
    }
    return parent::getAttributeValue($key);
}
```

The `decrypt()` cannot work on **non-encrypted** string. Right now you have some data in `task` column which is not encrypted and this `decrypt()` function is trying to decrypt a non-encrypted data.

Solution to this problem is you either decrypt all existing data in the `task` column or you could handle this in below way-

```
public function getAttributeValue($key)
{
    if(in_array($key, $this->getEncrypts())) {
        try {
            return decrypt($this->attributes[$key]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->attributes[$key];
        }
    }

    return parent::getAttributeValue($key);
}
```

This is taken from your **EncryptsAttributes.php** trait. I added try/catch block to handle this problem. If you have some data which is not encrypted then it will simply give you the data without trying to decrypt it.

Comment: Dear @Pankaj Amazing!!! Thank you very much! I really appreciate taking time for me. your code and your explain are really sweet! Thank you so much! You make my day!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. ^_^ Feel free to hit me up whenever you need me. And thanks for your kind words.